# Django manage.py command having SyntaxError on ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using AWS for first time, and after uploading my Django project I wanted to know how to backup the information of the DB into a file to be able to modify the data in case I have to modify the models of my project (still on development) and keep having some population data.

I thought about the `django dumpdata` command, so to be able to execute it on EB through the CLI I did the following (and here is where maybe I'm doing something wrong):

```
- eb ssh
- sudo -s
- cd /opt/python/current/app/
- python manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --natural-primary -e contenttypes -e auth.Permission --indent 4 > project_dump.json
```

For what I understand, the first command is just to access to the SSH on Elastic Beanstalk.

The second one is to have root permissions inside the linux server to evade problems creating and opening files, etc.

The third one is just to access where the current working aplication is.

And the last is the command I have to use to dump all the data "human friendly" without restrictions to be able to use it in any other new database.

> I have to say that I tried this last command on my local machine and
>   worked as expected without any error or warning.

So, the issue I'm facing here is that when I execute this last command, I get the following error:

```
  File "manage.py", line 14
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Also I tried to skip the `sudo -s` to just use the permissions of the user I'm using to log on the ssh, but got: `-bash: project_dump.json: Permission denied`. So that is why I thought using the `sudo` command would help here.

> In addition, I followed [this known tutorial](https://realpython.com/deploying-a-django-app-and-postgresql-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/#static-files) to deploy
>   Django+PostgreSQL on EB, so the user I'm using to access to `ssh` is
>   one in a group with `AdministratorAccess` permissions.

Before Trying all of this, I also looked for a way of having this information directly from `AWS-RDS`, but I only found a way of having a backup restored, but without being able to modify the content manually, so is not what I really need.

Comment: Looks like you're running the wrong python version. Check `python --version`. Should be > 3.5. Doesn't EB use a virtualenv setup?

Comment: run `source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate` and `source /opt/python/current/env` before running any management command. This activates your virtualenv and sets the environment variables used by settings.py.

Comment: you are right, I'm on 2.7.15 on EB, but my venv have "Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.7.7". Also I have in my `container_commands` the environment activated. But now that I'm looking at it, I got from the tutorial the activation of the virtualenv on every command (migrate, populate and collectstatic). So I have to activate it every time I have to access through ssh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As on your local environment, you need to run your `manage.py` commands inside your correct python virtualenv and make sure the environment variables like `RDS_USERNAME` and `RDS_PASSWORD` are set. To do that, you need to:

1. Activate your virtualenv
2. Source your environment variables

As described at the end of the tutorial you mentioned, this is how to do it:

```
source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate
source /opt/python/current/env
python manage.py <your_command>
```

And you have to do that every time you ssh into the machine.

Note: the reason you're getting the permission denied error is that when you pipe the output of `dumpdata` to *project_dump.json*, you're trying to write in the app directory itself. Not a good idea. Try piping to `> ~/project_dump.json` instead (your home directory), then sudo won't be needed.